# MySQL backing up MyISAM tables by copying the physical files - and automating the process

Tags: mysql, automation, backup, myisam

I have 2 databases with MyISAM tables running on a Windows 2008 Server. These databases are about 20GB in size with a few tables with millions of rows. My question regards backing them up on a weekly basis. Currently I do some updates once a week, and then I go to the data folder and copy the physical folders representing the databases to another drive on the server, and then rar everything up.

This process takes about 45 minutes and during that time certain functionality of my website cannot be used as during the copying, the tables get blocked. I have seen that you can LOCK and FLUSH tables so that they can still be used while they are being copied. So does LOCKing the tables allow concurrent SELECTs?

I do not know exactly how to go about this and I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me with how I could synchronize the lock/flush statements with the copying of the physical data and then the subsequent unlocking, and how I could possibly automate (possibly script to a dos batch file) this process?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: This question is probably better asked on **dba.stackexchange.com**.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a replication of your MySQL server (master-slave) and:

1. You will have a runtime copy of your current db on slave instance of MySQL.
2. You can stop slave instance of mysql, run backup process on slave and start replication again, it no affects the master instance and of course your site will no be affected.

The master-slave replication can be done in the same machine using a different disk or in another machine (recommended).

You can automate the process creating a .bat scripts to stop/run slave instances and backup process, and then add this .bat file to your windows task.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion - I guess I have to read a little about replication ass I do not yet know how to go about it...but thanks for pointing me to this idea!